# Unable execute this oracle procedure with springframework JdbcTemplate in Java? Error: Cannot perform fetch on a PLSQL statement :next;

Tags: java, spring, oracle, stored-procedures, jdbctemplate

I'm trying to execute a Oracle procedure using spring JdbcTemplate but getting following error :
 `Cannot perform fetch on PLSQL statement: next;`
This is the oracle procedure

```
create or replace PROCEDURE  PROCEDURE_NAME
AS
cursorname SYS_REFCURSOR;
variablename VARCHAR2(250);
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO tablename
    SELECT RTRIM(FIELDNAME)
           RTRIM(FIELDNAME2)
    FROM tablename2;
    WHERE OTHERFIELDNAME='CONDITIONSTRING'
    
    OPEN CURSORNAME FOR
    SELECT *
    FROM tablename;
    DBMS.SQL.RETURN_RESULT(cursorname);

EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
    variablename := SQLERRM;
    INSERT INTO debuggingtablename
    VALUES ('labelname', systimestamp, 'labelname2failname' || substr(variablename,1,120));

   RETURN;
END;
```

And I'm calling it as

```
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;

public Classname {
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

public List<Map<String,Object>> getdata(){
return jdbcTemplate.queryForList("CALL PROCEDURE_NAME()",new Object[]{});
}
```

1. I'm not allowed to edit/modify the procedure code.
2. If there is no solution without modifying the procedure is there anyway I can get the output in List<Map<String,Object>> format where column name and values are mapped to each other.
3. This procedure does not take any input but some other procedure might do in future.

PS: I have simplified the program so ignore any grammar mistakes.

Comment: I think the use of `RETURN_RESULT` requires the use of `stmt.getMoreResults()` in Java, and I don't believe Spring has built-in support for that, so it's up to you to do that, e.g. by calling `jdbcTemplate.execute(String sql, PreparedStatementCallback<T> action)`.

Comment: `queryForList` doesn't expect to be used with procedures because it doesn't return result. Use `execute` as Andreas  suggest.

Comment: @Andreas Will this method jdbcTemplate.execute(String sql, PreparedStatementCallback<T> action) give me the result in List<Map<String,Object>> format?. If not is there anyway to get that in that format? by using stmt.getMoreResults() ?

Comment: It will if `T` is `List<Map<String,Object>>` and your code creates that.

Comment: You have to do it all using JDBC in your implementation of the `PreparedStatementCallback` interface.

Comment: @Andreas So I tried this `jdbcTemplate.execute("sql", new Object[]{});` but I'm not able to. Can you please show me any example to get return in `List<Map<String,Object>>` format using `jdbcTemplate.execute`

Comment: @Andreas I saw PreparedStatementCallback interface in that I could only find the return as boolean value in examples I saw.

Comment: What do you mean "only find the return as boolean value"? The [`doInPreparedStatement(...)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.2.9.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/PreparedStatementCallback.html#doInPreparedStatement-java.sql.PreparedStatement-) method of `PreparedStatementCallback` returns `T`, and I already said that `T` is `List<Map<String,Object>>`, so where is that `boolean`? **Read the documentation** of the API you're using and/or going to implement.